# How do i handle a heavy page?

Tags: asp.net

I have been asked to design & develop a page in asp.net which contains 7 tabs.Each table contains 2 Editable gridview & clicking on gridview cell should open a popup & that popup will open a new popup ( I would say nested popup). even when i switch from one tab to another. It should hold the griddata & whenever user will finish all the operations he/she will click on save button which will save all the data contained in the tabs.
The page is really too too too heavy. It will definitely take a long time to load as it contains gridview operations , popup related jobs, tab data & tab switching.
I am finding the best way i can achieve this with an acceptable speed of operation. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With all of the web-based controls (tabs, grids, anything that uses an intensive postback model) included in ASP.NET, plus those made by 3rd party vendors (Telerik, Infragistics, and the like), it is possible to make very **big** web pages. And I've made more than a few in my days. Tabs. Multiple update panels. Drop-downs created from dozens of sources. I have decided to remember one simple fact:

```
WEB_APPLICATION != CLIENT_SERVER
```

**Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.** If changing the UI is not an option, keep in mind the following

Look into paging your grid views. Limiting the amount of data rendered on the page will speed up the page.

You can look at caching operations. If you have access to modern browsers, you can make use of isolated local storage on the client. This will be even faster than caching on the server, but you're limited to the really new stuff.

Become a big friend of partial page loads and AJAX operations. You can still build a bigger UI, but keep the actual data operations small and focused. Data-driven drop downs on a hidden tab can be loaded after the visible components of the page have loaded.

I've made a lot of customers very happy because I keep my UI's incredibly fast, and they never break. I keep them fast by keeping them focused. A page is built for a single task. Design for simplicity into UI. You will not be sorry.

Answer (score 1):

- Paging.
- Caching.
- Lazy Loading (through Ajax).

Comment: It would be nice if u can explain me in detail where to use each of these features in my scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a ASP.net programmer but I think you need to go back to the basics. I am assuming that gridviews are tables.

You could look into the following basic optimizations:
each of your 7 tabs could be a separate http request, that would cut down your load times by 7 for starters
Possible use a combination of cookies and session objects to hold on to the data in the other 6 tabs.

Also, as @LordCover suggested:
Look into ASP.net caching options if any
Use Ajax where you can (editable table cells)

Also, think in terms of the HTML being generated from the ASP page rather than have a completely ASP centric mindset around this.

Also do not rule out a UI redesign, there are many ways to do the same thing. You may be able to break up the UI into simpler pages